# It is possible to create native add-ins for outlook by using swift/ objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, applet, outlook-addin

I have a requirement to create add-ins for mac outlook which should be developed as native (not via:- html/javascript/css), It should developed with swift/Objective-c
any resource or Documents from apple/Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook for Mac only supports JS web addin. There is nothing like COM addins for the Windows version of Outlook, which can be written in any natively compiled language.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko for response.

Comment: @SanjayMishra - if the answer answers your question, please mark it as such.